# Idiomatic way to wait for Deployment to be really scaled down

Tags: kubernetes

For tests, I want to have a way of waiting until a Deployment (replicas: 0) is really gone.

It seems like the Deployment Status is not waiting for all Pods to actually be terminated.

So I am wondering what the idiomatic way of waiting for a Deployment to be terminated is.
In other words, I want to have synchronous Delete of a Resource in Kubernetes, which also only returns after all Owning Resources (recursively) got deleted.

Answer (score 3):

I think that Kubernetes 1.11+ already waits for the deletion to be completed before delete returns:

> `kubectl delete --help | grep '\-\-wait'`
>   --wait=true: If true, wait for resources to be gone before returning. This waits for finalizers.

Even so, you can use [`kubectl wait`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#wait) to wait for a resource deletion:

> Wait for a specific condition on one or many resources. Alternatively,
>   the command can wait for the given set of resources to be deleted by
>   providing the "delete" keyword as the value to the `--for` flag.

e.g: `kubectl wait deployment/my-deployment --for=delete`

Comment: Are you sure, that `wait --for=delete` does wait for its' owning Resources to be deleted? Cannot seem to find any docs for that.

Comment: Thanks for that. It works as intended, Here are some examples from my project:
`kubectl wait --namespace $NAMESPACE --for=delete persistentvolumeclaim/$RELEASE_NAME --timeout=90s`

and

`kubectl wait --namespace $NAMESPACE --for=delete pod --selector=$APP_LABEL --timeout=90s`

Comment: it doesn't seem to work for deployments, the k8s resource 'deployment' is gone immediately, while the pods are still shutting down.

Answer (score 2):

Your `pods` ( dependents) have `metadata.ownerReferences` pointing to your `Deployment` (owner) and by design they should be removed first from Kubernetes 1.8.
In docs about [owners and dependents](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/garbage-collection/#owners-and-dependents) it says:

> Sometimes, Kubernetes sets the value of `ownerReference` automatically. For example, when you create a ReplicaSet, Kubernetes automatically sets the `ownerReference` field of each Pod in the ReplicaSet. In 1.8, Kubernetes automatically sets the value of `ownerReference` for objects created or adopted by ReplicationController, ReplicaSet, StatefulSet, DaemonSet, Deployment, Job and CronJob.

You can check for that value by using `kubectl get pods --output=yaml`

[Controlling how the garbage collector deletes dependents](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/garbage-collection/#controlling-how-the-garbage-collector-deletes-dependents) says:

> When you delete an object, you can specify whether the object’s dependents are also deleted automatically. Deleting dependents automatically is called  *cascading deletion*. There are two modes of  *cascading deletion*:  *background*  and  *foreground*.
>
> If you delete an object without deleting its dependents automatically, the dependents are said to be  *orphaned*.

***Foreground*** object enters "deletion in progress" state, in that state following are true:

- The object is still visible via the REST API
- The object’s  `deletionTimestamp`  is set
- The object’s  `metadata.finalizers`  contains the value “foregroundDeletion”.

Once the garbage collector removes all “blocking” dependents (objects with `ownerReference.blockOwnerDeletion=true`), it deletes the owner object.

> Note that in the “foregroundDeletion”, only dependents with  `ownerReference.blockOwnerDeletion=true`  block the deletion of the owner object. **Kubernetes version 1.7** added an  [admission controller](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/admission-controllers/#ownerreferencespermissionenforcement)  that controls user access to set  `blockOwnerDeletion`  to true based on delete permissions on the owner object, so that unauthorized dependents cannot delay deletion of an owner object.
>
> If an object’s  `ownerReferences`  field is set by a controller (such as Deployment or ReplicaSet), blockOwnerDeletion is set automatically and you do not need to manually modify this field.

In ***Background*** cascading deletion Kubernetes deletes the owner immediately and then garbage collector deletes the dependents in the background.

As for `kubectl wait` it depends what `resource.group` you will set it to, because it does not care about any dependent resources but only observed `resource.group`.

Comment: Thanks. These details at least inspired me to handle `deleteTimestamp` for our CRs. Still it seems to miss the point of waiting for all depending pods to be terminated. So currently the only solution I can think of is to drill down via ownership _Deployment_ -> _ReplicaSet_ -> _Pod_. And before e.g. doing any delete setup a concurrent check that polls for these Pods to be actually terminated. This seems brittle.

Comment: @abergmeier, Yes as far as I know that would be only sure solution.